# how to get mime type from content-type

Tags: javascript, api, axios

The thing is axios calls return files. sometimes xlsx, sometimes plain txt.

In javascript, as soon as I get them, i force download it via blob.

Something like this:

```
var headers = response.headers;
var blob = new Blob([response.data], {
    type: headers['content-type']
});
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = "report.xlsx";
link.click();
```

As you see, I got something like this: `link.download = "report.xlsx"` . What I want is to replace **xlsx** with dynamic mime type so that sometimes it's **report.txt** and sometimes it's **report.xlsx**.

How do I do that from content-type?

Comment: That would be great if it's useful you can accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275507/how-to-get-mime-type-from-content-type/58276040#58276040

Answer (score 2):

You can get the file extension using the content type of headers. 

Use this Javascript library - [node-mime](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime)

You just want to pass your `headers['content-type']`, it will give you the file extension which you need to set for download name.

```js
var ctype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

console.log(mime.getExtension(ctype));
```

```html
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/mime@latest"></script>
```

**Example:** In your case,

```
var headers = response.headers;
var blob = new Blob([response.data], {
    type: headers['content-type']
});
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = "report." + mime.getExtension(headers['content-type']);
link.click();
```

[Incomplete list of MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) from Mozilla Developers.

Comment: would be great without any other plugins.

Comment: Then you have to write your own array to identify xlsx and txt files

Comment: Refer this URL : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/ , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

Answer (score 1):

What is the backend of your application? I used this in C# (.NET Core) to get the content type of a file then set it as a header in the response:

```
public string GetContentType (string filePath) {
    var contentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    string contentType;
    if( !contentTypeProvider.TryGetContentType( filePath, out contentType ) ) {
        contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    };
    return contentType;
}
```

Edit: modified OP code to handle content type dynamically:

```
var headers = response.headers;
var responseType = headers['content-type'];
var fileType = "text/plain";
var fileName = "report.txt";
if ( responseType == "application/octet-stream" ) {
    fileType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    fileName = "report.xlsx";
}
var blob = new Blob([response.data], {
    type: fileType
});
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = fileName;
link.click();
```

Comment: that gets returned already. Sometimes Content-Type is application/octet-stream sometimes it's text/plain. The thing is that when I download file in js, i have to name it. as I can't get if it's 'xlsx' or 'txt', i can't name the file dynamically. makes sense?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I modified your code to handle different content types. The default is plain text file and otherwise it's an excel file. However with this approach you should be aware that it will be treated only as excel if the content type is not plain text.